# Keycloak java servlet adapter get roles and scopes

Tags: jakarta-ee, scope, roles, keycloak, security-context

I'm currently implementing a webb app with JEE7 on a glassfish 4. With that I'm using Keycloak as a security provider which lead me to use the KeycloakOIDCFilter java servlet filter to get the combo working.

For now the login and logout is no problem, but I need the scopes and roles too.
Therefor, my question is:

Ho do I obtain these? I've seen the examples with the security and authorization context but I can not access them, as the servlet filter only sets the keycloak deployment context as servlet context attribute not the security or authentication context.

I already tried understanding what happens in the wildfly / jboss implementations, but that lead me nowhere.

Comment: Do you mean you are not able to get hold of  KeycloakSecurityContext,  AuthorizationContext

Comment: Have checked the example here https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/master/app-authz-jee-servlet

Comment: Have you found a solution on this? I'm facing the same issue..